# How to find client from bills by id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to find client from bills by id client, but it shows me an error.

I've tried to get client id using function "findById"

this is the Client schema:

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const { Schema } = mongoose;

    const clientSchema = new Schema({

    name: String,
    mail: String,
    cuil: String,
    phone: Number,
    address: {street: String,
    number: Number,
    floor: String,
    flat: Number
    }    
    });

    mongoose.model('clients', clientSchema);
```

Bill schema:

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const { Schema } = mongoose;

    const billSchema = new Schema({

    number: Number,

    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},

    type: String,

    local: String,

    client: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'clients'
    },

    detail: [{
        quantity Number,

        product: {code: Number,
                   number: String,
                   price: Number
        },
        undertotal: Number
    }
    ],
    total: Number

    });

    mongoose.model('bills', billSchema);
```

And by last, my get route

```js
     app.get('/api/bills/client/:id', (req, res) => {
        console.info('Obtaining bill's client');
        try{
          const id = req.body.client._id;
        const client = Bill.findById(id)
        .populate("client","address name mail cuil phone -_id");

        if (client) {
          res.send(client);
      } else {
          res.status(404).send({ message: `Client '${id}' couldn't be found. ` 
    });
      }
      } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send({ message: `Internal server error.\n\n${err}` });
      }

          });
```

I expected shows me the client from bill.
The output shows me "Internal server error". How can I solve this error?.

Is better using function "find" instead "findById"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to pass the clientId through  req.body or inside the route parameter?

I think it must be in route parameter since you have already expect it in url like this "/api/bills/client/:id"

Note: findOne (or findById) returns promise so you need to use await (or then block))

```
app.get("/api/bills/client/:id", async (req, res) => {
  console.info("Obtaining bills client");
  try {
    const id = req.params.id; //   req.body.client._id;
    const client = await Bill.findOne({ client: id }).populate(
      "client",
      "address name mail cuil phone -_id"
    );

    if (client) {
      res.send(client);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: `Client '${id}' couldn't be found. ` });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ message: `Internal server error.\n\n${err}` });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are finding bill id, then how will you get data, Try for the following:

```
    const id = req.body.client._id;
    const client = Bill.findOne({client:id})
    .populate("client","address name mail cuil phone -_id");
```